# How to print the string without duplicate?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I tried to print the string without duplicate but i not getting the proper output and here I exposed my code snippets.

```
class Duplicatestring
{
public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    String word = "";
            String[]  ip ={"mani" ," manivannan","raghv ","mani"};  
    for(int i =0; i<ip.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j<=ip.length; j++)
        {
                if(ip[i].equals(ip[j])){ 
            word = word+ip[i];

        }
        }
        System.out.println(word);

    }       

    }
}
```

And one more thing is I don't want use the *collections* that is my task and pleas give any proper solution for this.

Example:

```
Input -> {mani, manivanna,raghv, mani};
output -> {mani, manivanna,raghv}
```

Comment: @RJ sorry but it will throw an error you are trying to access the length element. mean if length is **n** then you are trying to access the **ip[n]** which will throw an error

Comment: j<=ip.length will throw ArayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @TheLostMind can give me rectified code..

Comment: now you know the error.try to correct it yourself. rather than asking from another

Comment: @user3164190 i have posted an answer check that..!! it will hopefully work for you.

Comment: That's not the way it goes here. Think about your algorithm. It should simply be: iterate through the array, print the current element unless a previous element in the array is equal to the current one. So start by writing a method for "does a given element exist in the array before a given index".

Comment: @user3164190 - We can't give you code.. ᴍaroun ᴍaroun's answer will be your guide :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use *collections* then I assume it's a homework, so I don't want to provide you a full solution, but I'll guide you.

You can have a helper array of the size of the original array. Now you write two nested loops and for each word, if you find a duplicate, you mark the helper array with 1.

After this procedure you'll have something like this in the helper array:

```
[0,0,0,1]
```

Now you iterate on the arrays in parallel and print the element *only* if the corresponding index in the helper array is 0.

Solution is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is incorrect. 
To solve the problem, you can use a `Set` to eliminate duplicated words.

If the problem must be solved by O(n^2) loops, the following code will work:

```
public class Duplicatestring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] ip = { "mani", " manivannan", "raghv ", "mani" };
        for (int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {

            boolean duplicated = false;

            //search back to check if a same word already exists
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if(ip[i].equals(ip[j])) {
                    duplicated = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!duplicated) {
                System.out.println(ip[i]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer so far. Would be better if the duplicate check was in its own method.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the duplicate from the array call the below method and pass the array has the duplicate values.. it will return you the array with non-duplicate values..

```
call method here
ip = removeDuplicates(ip);
```

---

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] arr){
    //dest array index
    int destination = 0;

    //source array index
    int source = 0;

    int currentValue = arr[0];

    int[] whitelist = new int[arr.length];
    whitelist[destination] = currentValue;
    while(source < arr.length){

        if(currentValue == arr[source]){
            source++;
        } else {
            currentValue = arr[source];
            destination++;
            source++;
            whitelist[destination] = currentValue;
        }
    }
    int[] returnList = new int[++destination];

    for(int i = 0; i < destination; i++){
        returnList[i] = whitelist[i];
    }

    return returnList;
}
```

it will return you the non duplicates values array..!!

Answer (score 0):

u may try this:

```
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String[] names = {"john", "adam", "will", "lee", "john", "seon", "lee"};
    String s;
    for (int i = 0; names.length > i; i ++) {
        s = names[i];
        if (!isDuplicate(s, i, names)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
 }
 private static boolean isDuplicate(String item, int j, String[] items) {
    boolean duplicate = Boolean.FALSE;
     for (int i = 0; j > i; i++) {
         if (items[i].equals(item)) {
             duplicate = Boolean.TRUE;
             break;
         }
     }
     return duplicate;
 }
}
```

**output**

```
john
adam
will
lee
seon
```

Answer (score -1):

if string order does not matter for you, you can also use the TreeSet.. check the below code.. simple and sweet.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MyArrayDuplicates { 
    public static void main(String a[]){
        String[] strArr = {"one","two","three","four","four","five"};
        //convert string array to list
        List<String> tmpList = Arrays.asList(strArr);
        //create a treeset with the list, which eliminates duplicates
        TreeSet<String> unique = new TreeSet<String>(tmpList);
        System.out.println(unique);
        System.out.println();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = unique.iterator();

       // Displaying the Tree set data
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
       }
    }
}
```

it will print as -

```
[five, four, one, three, two]

five
four
one
three
two
```

Comment: i have provided you the both way to print the values in TreeSet. **All in one shot and one-by-one**

Comment: *I don't want use the collections that is my task*. Why use a TreeSet rather than a HashSet or LinkedHashSet? Why not use a foreach loop?

Comment: i am not to debit for this topic **why this / why not that etc etc**, if I use HashSet you will say why not **TreeSet**. So i dont have any answer for such questions.!

Comment: hmm well i have provided then another solution also.. that may help him...!!

Comment: That's the problem. You don't have the answer. A HashSet or LinkedHashSet is O(1). A TreeSet is O(log n) and is used to have sorted entries in the set, which is not what the suer asked for. You just picked the less efficient data structure for no good reason.